# Colouring points, smoothed lines and confidence intervals according to grouping in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, smoothing

I have created a graph using ggplot2 which is coloured according to my groups (i.e., gnc and mr). However, I was not able to change the default colours of all elements (points, smoothed lines, confidence intervals + how they appear in the legend) respecting my grouping (i.e., one unique colour for all elements related to gnc and another unique colour for all elements related to mr). What would be the best way forward? Any help much appreciated!

The dataset:

```
    lat<-c(37.30,37.30,37.30,37.30,69.25,69.25,37.30,0.00,0.00,37.30,37.30,37.30,37.30,-75.00,-75.00,70.00,25.30,25.30,37.30,45.00,46.75,-49.00,-49.00,-49.00,58.50,-37.00,37.30,37.30,37.30,37.30,69.25,69.25,37.30,0.00,0.00,37.30,37.30,37.30,37.30,-75.00,-75.00,70.00,25.30,25.30,37.30,-49.00,-49.00,-49.00,16.10,-9.12,50.00,30.00)
    prop<-c(64, 62, 38, 37, 50, 30, 27, 10, 25, 39, 25,  6,  5, 25, 47, 24, 20,  2, 62, 40, 48, 60, 20, 40, 66, 57, 14, 25, 11,  0,  3,  5,  0,  0,  0, 14, 10, 11, 9,  1,  1, 34, 20, 90,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  5, 85,  6)
    group<-c("gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","gnc","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr","mr")
    mydata<-data.frame(lat,prop,group)
    newtype<-factor(group,levels=c("gnc","mr"))
```

The graph:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)

    ggplot(data=mydata,aes(x=lat,y=prop,colour=newtype))+
      geom_point(size=2.3) +
      stat_smooth(span=0.75,n=26,method="loess",aes(fill=newtype)) +
      theme_bw()+
      theme(
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0.15,0.85),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_text(size=17),
        axis.title=element_text(size=19),
        legend.text=element_text(size=17)
      )+
      scale_y_continuous(limit=c(0,NA),oob=squish)+ 
      scale_x_continuous(limit=c(-70,70),oob=squish,breaks=c(-60,-30,0,30,60))
```

Comment: (a) Why are you creating a vector outside of your data frame that is a copy of your `group` column? You should reference data frame columns in `aes()` or complicated plots (e.g., with facets or data summaries) won't work. Just use `colour = group` and `fill = group`.

Comment: (b) When I run your code either as-is or with the correction suggested above, it works fine. I get a plot with points, smooths, and lines colored according to `gnc` or `mr` and a single legend indicating all of that together. What do you want to change?

Comment: The code works; what I don't know is how to change the default colours. I did not choose the colours that appear in my plot (light blue and salmon), they are the default. How could I change, for example, all that is light blue to yellow and all that is salmon to green?

Comment: See the scale functions, such as `scale_color_manual`/`scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: `my_col = c("yellow", "darkolivegreen1"); ... + scale_color_manual(values = my_col) + scale_fill_manual(values = my_col)`